# Setting ViewSheetSetting.InSession.Views Property

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

Has anyone worked with setting the `InSession.Views` property? 
The problem I have is that when I set the following property immediately after opening a document it doesn't work (i.e. the Views size is still 0 even though the `viewSet` has 4 items).

```
revitDocument.PrintManager.ViewSheetSetting.InSession.Views = viewSet;
```

but after modifying the In-Session view/sheet set using print dialog in `revit`, then I can assign to it.

does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revit stores the current view sheet set in the variable `Document.PrintManager.ViewSheetSetting.CurrentViewSheetSet` and that's what it's really using .  At the beginning when you are setting the `InSession` you should be setting the `CurrentViewSheetSet` instead.  The reason that it is working after using the print dialog is that it is setting the `CurrentViewSheetSet` to `InSession`.  What I would do is to create a temporary `ViewSheetSetting` on document open and then delete it when the document closes.  Below is some of the code that I used though with mine I only kept the `ViewSheetSetting` for the scope of a single function call instead of from document open to document close.

**For Open**

```
const string tempoarySheetSetSettingName = "Temp Sheet Set";

ViewSheetSetting viewSheetSetting = _printManager.ViewSheetSetting;

//Save your temporary sheet set
_printManager.ViewSheetSetting.SaveAs(tempoarySheetSetSettingName);

ViewSheetSet selected = null;

FilteredElementCollector viewCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(document);
viewCollector.OfClass(typeof(ViewSheetSet));

//Find the sheet set that you just created
foreach (ViewSheetSet set in viewCollector.ToElements())
{
  if (String.Compare(set.Name, tempoarySheetSetSettingName) == 0)
  {
    selected = set;
    break;
  }
}

//Set the current view sheet set to the one that you just created
viewSheetSetting.CurrentViewSheetSet = selected;

//Set the views to which ever set you would like to print
viewSheetSetting.CurrentViewSheetSet.Views = viewSetToPrint;
viewSheetSetting.Save();
```

**For Printing**

Your user will need to select the temporary view set that you created whenever they print.

**For Close**

```
_printManager.ViewSheetSetting.Delete();
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I figured this long ago and temporary viewsheetset was what I did at the end...

Answer (score 0):

In Revit 2015 using VB.Net I couldn't force this ViewSheetSet Colletor to work like this:

```
Dim VSSCollector As New FilteredElementCollector(curDoc)
VSSCollector.OfClass(oftype(ViewSheetSet))
```

Instead I used this and it worked:

```
Dim VSSCollector As New FilteredElementCollector(curDoc)
VSSCollector.OfClass(GetType(ViewSheetSet))
```